# Validação CPF e CNPJ

Tags: ios, swift

Andei fazendo uma pesquisa em Swift e não vi exemplos que contemple a validação tanto de CPF e CNPJ. Portanto, algum dos colegas tem uma função que possa valida-los?

Comment: Caso não queira fazer a função manualmente, eu recomento essa lib:
https://github.com/fpg1503/CPF-CNPJ-Validator

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/196879)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Validação CPF**

Para validar o primeiro digito do CPF voce precisa multiplicar cada digito (do 1º ao 9º) começando por 10 e diminuindo gradativamente até 2 e acumular o total das multiplicações. Depois pega-se 11 e subtrai-se o resto do acumulado dividido por 11. Se o resultado for maior que 9 o primeiro digito verificador é 0 senão é o próprio resultado.

Para o segundo digito verificador o método é praticamente o mesmo só que usa-se do 1º ao 10º digito e a multiplicação começa em 11 em vez de 10:

---

**Swift 5.2 ou posterior**

```
extension Collection where Element == Int {
    var digitoCPF: Int {
        var number = count + 2
        let digit = 11 - reduce(into: 0) {
            number -= 1
            $0 += $1 * number
        } % 11
        return digit > 9 ? 0 : digit
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isValidCPF: Bool {
        let numbers = compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue)
        guard numbers.count == 11 && Set(numbers).count != 1 else { return false }
        return numbers.prefix(9).digitoCPF == numbers[9] &&
               numbers.prefix(10).digitoCPF == numbers[10]
    }
}
```

---

**Validação CNPJ**

A validação do digito de verificação do CNPJ é bem parecida com a do CPF. Para validar o primeiro digito do CNPJ voce precisa multiplicar cada digito na ordem inversa (do 12º ao 1º) começando por 2 e aumentando gradativamente até 9 e depois do 2 até 5 e acumular o total das multiplicações. Depois pega-se 11 e subtrai-se o resto do acumulado dividido por 11. Se o resultado for maior que 9 o digito verificador é 0 senão é o igual ao próprio resultado.

Para o segundo digito verificador o método é praticamente o mesmo só que usa-se do 13º ao 1º digito e a multiplicação acaba em 6 em vez de 5:

```
extension Collection where Element == Int {
    var digitoCNPJ: Int {
        var number = 1
        let digit = 11 - reversed().reduce(into: 0) {
            number += 1
            $0 += $1 * number
            if number == 9 { number = 1 }
        } % 11
        return digit > 9 ? 0 : digit
    }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isValidCNPJ: Bool {
        let numbers = compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue)
        guard numbers.count == 14 && Set(numbers).count != 1 else { return false }
        return numbers.prefix(12).digitoCNPJ == numbers[12] &&
               numbers.prefix(13).digitoCNPJ == numbers[13]
    }
}
```

---

**Playground**

```
let cpf1 = "957.621.155-77"
let cpf2 = "746.043.382-99"
let cpf3 = "111.111.111-11"

cpf1.isValidCPF  // true
cpf2.isValidCPF  // true
cpf3.isValidCPF  // false

let cnpj1 = "25.559.813/0001-47"
let cnpj2 = "76.702.537/0001-65"
let cnpj3 = "22.222.222/2222-22"

cnpj1.isValidCNPJ  // true
cnpj2.isValidCNPJ  // true
cnpj3.isValidCNPJ  // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Complemento a resposta de @LeoDabus
Há uma pequena falha no algorítmo de CPF.
O seguinte CPF deveria ser validado: `422.496.250-00`
Porém não está sendo.

Corrigir
 `return digit % 10` para `return digit >= 10 ? 0 : digit`

No exemplo citado acima, o resto da divisāo por 11 da soma dos produtos resulta em 0, pois a divisāo resulta num quociente inteiro, logo `11 - 0 = 11`

Portanto, o resto da divisāo de 11 por 10 é 1, quando que pelas regras do CPF e CNPJ, números maiores que 10 devem retornar 0 como dígito verificador.